# Retrieving count of objects every period of time using python

Tags: python, date, datetime, object-detection, object-tracking

I wanna ask for help concerning my object detection project.
So,I'm stuck in how I will make the count of vehicles every 1 hour to analyze the traffic jam  every period of time (I'm new to programming btw)

Comment: Please have another look at [ask] and try to provide *specific question*, with a [mre] of what doesn't work as you expect etc. You don't have to be an experienced programmer for this btw. ;-)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.